# Having download/latency issues with ESRI JS-API recently?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is anyone using the ESRI JS-API having issues over the last week or two with either latency or performance in the client download and operation? Since about 7/12/2011 we have seen across numerous ISPs and Browser/OS platforms in WA state issues with users getting the application to load and operate normally. 
 The only workaround I have had is to switch my app to using the compact api, to reduce the download footprint.

Comment: Another possible workaround would be to download the API, put it on your server, and reference all of your app's to the local API. It's not always feasible, but it will save the hops to/from Esri's servers if you have the bandwidth and server resources.

Comment: Kevin; yes that is one option I am considering; but these are blade-servers which have a smaller back-plane so there are concerns with throughput from my network folks but I am looking at that as a option too.

Comment: They have a pretty aggressive cache expiration of a year, that said, I disable caching and it's taken around 3-10 seconds a few times lately. Today though its half a second. Only way to remove that unknown is to host it yourself and see if you get better performance.

Comment: This question may be somewhat related to GIS (although it probably fits better on sites about servers), but according to our [FAQ](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#close) it's too localized (in time) to be of lasting value on this site.